# AuthorizationPolicy based on shared secret in url without authentication or identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

Because of a limitation of an external api, a pre-shared secret in the url is the only way we're going to be able to somewhat securely communicate. They will post messages to our server.

I made a custom policy in the standard asp.net core way that actually should be able to do this now.
It would get the secret injected and compare that to the query params by the injected ContextProvider.

Now I can't use that without `UseAuthentication()` and because I don't really have any authentication or Identity, how would I use this?

I have this now solved via a Custom Middleware on a route, but preferably it should be done via the AuthorizationPolicy. Is this possible?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, Authorization and Authentication are closely linked. If you do not want to set up authentication service, to achieve your requirement of checking res-shared secret passed in url, you can implement custom middleware (as you are doing) or custom filter.

Comment: "because I don't really have any authentication or Identity" but you do have authentication, you are looking to implement shared secret authentication. You can implement a custom authentication scheme for this and then use the authorization system as normal. I have an article related to this: https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2